# Appy different themes to jQuery-dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme

I have a page with the following jQuery scripts/theme included. The default theme I want is 'ui-lightness' for all applicable elements, but I would like the jQuery dialog boxes to be styled according to the 'cupertino' theme. How would I implement this requirement in my page?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at a dialog element.  Look at the classes that are added when you create one.  Then look in the respective css files and copy the cupertino theme classes into the lightness css file replacing the classes in the lightness file.  It's all styled with css and all the classes are named the same (I believe) so it will work fine if you just make the semi-custom css file.

Comment: I don't think its as simple as exchanging the CSS styling between 2 themes. I did that but it made no difference. What determines the back color of dialog title bar and what determines the look of the dialog button?

Comment: You are correct. I think, one needs to replace the CSS under /* Component containers */ plus copy all necessary image file to images folder to create a mixed theme, according to your suggestion.  But, one has to be careful that other elements besides the dialog control do not get changed in their CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

I think all jquery ui classes starts with `ui-` so you could find the dialog widget and change all the styles in it that starts with `ui-` to say `Xui-` and have the other theme have classes with the `Xui-` instead of the `ui-`

```
var widget = $('#dialog').dialog('widget');
widget.find('[class^=ui-]').add(widget).each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var classes = $this.attr('class');
    $.each(classes.split(' '), function(i, v){
        if (v.indexOf('ui-') == 0){
            this.removeClass(v);
            this.addClass('X'+v);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I will try out your suggestion. Seems like a neat idea. Thanks

Comment: @Musa- Thanks for your effort. I guess adjusting the CSS is the best and most straightforward way.